# Queryset in a while loop django

Tags: mysql, django, database, performance, data-structures

I'm using the queryset below and i'm quite new to Database's i want to know if  it's not too much expensive to do so or if it is, suggest an alternative way?

```
while active_user is None:
    active_user = Users.objects.filter(is_active=True).first()
```

the `is_active` field is indexed in database (`db_index=True`) and the while loop won't take more than 2-3 mins. using `MySql`.

Comment: Do it in a single SQL statement, not a loop.

Comment: i don't want to do anything else if an active user not found, there must be at least one active user to progress. that's why i put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough to know for sure, but [Django's signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/) might do what you're looking to accomplish. Once they're set up, you can trigger a signal after a User is created by listening to its [`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save). The signal has a `created` argument that will be `True` only when a new User is created. The following example is adapted from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders).

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(pre_save, sender=get_user_model())
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created'):
        # Do what you're looking to do here
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what i'm looking for.

Comment: @garetHollamdaf Glad that I could help!